# expected';' before '[' token

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, arduino

I absolutely can not understand what could possibly be wrong with my code, but I am probably missing something. I have searched for similar problems regarding other tokens, but they have been useless to me. Since my code is not very long, I will go ahead and post it here.

```
unsigned int value;
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <avr/power.h>
#endif
#define PIN 6
#define NUM_LEDS 60
#define BRIGHTNESS 10
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup (){
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.setTimeout(50000);
strip.begin();
strip.setBrightness(BRIGHTNESS);
strip.begin();
strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop ()
{
boolean lights;
int value[100];

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
value[i] = analogRead(0);
}

int j=SmallestElement(value);

if(value[j-1]-value[j]>=2 and value[j-1]-value[j]<=30) and value[j-2]-value[j-1]>=2 and value[j-2]-value[j-1]<=30 and value[j+1]-value[j]>50 and value[j+2]>value[j+1]){ //THE COMPILER IS NOT OKAY WITH THIS LINE
lights = true; //THE COMPILER HAS A PROBLEM WITH THE LINE ABOVE
}
else{
lights=false;
}

if(lights){    //if there is a characteristic drop
if(value[j]>=600 and value[j]<=699){
int   one=0;
for(int j=0;j<60;j++){
strip.setPixelColor(j,0,0,0);
}
for(int i=0;i<15;i++,one++){
strip.setPixelColor(one,0,255,0);
strip.show();
delay(10);
}
}
if(value[j]>=500 and value[j]<=599){
int    two1=0,two2=60;
for(int j=0;j<60;j++){
strip.setPixelColor(j,0,0,0);
}
for(int i=0;i<30;i++,two1++,two2--){
strip.setPixelColor(two1,255,255,0);
strip.setPixelColor(two2,255,255,0);
strip.show();
delay(10);
}
  }

}

  }

int SmallestValue(int values[100]){
int smallest = values[0];
for(int i=1;i<100;i++){
if(values[i]<smallest){
smallest=values[i];
}
  }
return smallest;
}

int SmallestElement(int values[100]){
int i=0;
while(values[i]!=SmallestValue(values){
  i++;
 }
 return i;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: If you formatted your code properly, you would more than likely find the error.

Comment: The formatting is actually because I'm not familiar with formatting the code here. In my compiler it is pretty clear.

Comment: You seem to have an extra `)` after `<=30` before the second `and`?

Comment: `formatting … not familiar … here. In my compiler it is pretty clear.` - did you cut&paste the code, mark it and type `Ctrl+K`? ((doesn't quite look that way.) Don't hand-edit code containing tabs - de-tab before pasting if you plan to edit.)

Answer (score 4):

Your if statement has mismatched parentheses.

Your code:

```
if(
    value[j-1]-value[j]>=2 and 
    value[j-1]-value[j]<=30) and // <- Paren here closes the if(
    value[j-2]-value[j-1]>=2 and 
    value[j-2]-value[j-1]<=30 and 
    value[j+1]-value[j]>50 and 
    value[j+2]>value[j+1]){ 
    lights = true; 
}
else{
    lights=false;
}
```

Notepad is nice but take advantage of an IDE!

Comment: And you have no idea how many times i stared my soul into that line. Thank you so much. I'll definitely be using the notepad solution next time.